# Which is better? Qt Creator or Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio, qt, ide, qt-creator

I am currently using Qt Creator 1.3 for my Qt applications. I know it uses **jom** for **make** step which is better when we have multi-core processors. But besides that what are all the advantages of using both the IDEs? Dis advantages as well? I am using the CL compiler though for compiling my applications. Are there any other specific advantages and disadvantages of these IDEs?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am using QtCreator for development of my Qt applications because I it better fits the Qt classes as such. However I use Visual Studio for Debugging those projects.

Qt-Creator:

- better Qt object support (help, navigation, etc.)
- better GUI editor
- some nice features like mouse navigation
- really fast IDE
- poor debugging (at least I don't know how to efficiently use it here) compared to VS

Visual Studio (+Visual Assist):

- great debugger
- Visual Assist
- easier project file configuration and customization (qmake is way too limited in some areas)
- Visual Studio is my choice for C++ development (I'm used to it)
- Qt integration is not that good (IMHO)

Comment: In VS, the debugger features I use and like a lot are (besides basics like step, jump into, jump over):
- Data access/modify breakpoints
- Locals & watch
- Modify variables
- Navigate stack trace
- Change program counter (jump to without executing).
According to [Qt doc on debugging](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debug-mode.html) these are all possible in Qt Creator. I heard of ridiculously high level VS debugger features like modify and recompile a part of the program, patch it into the running debugged program, and resume debugger session, but I never needed such thing.

Comment: Add something regarding VS Code I would say, which replaces more or less Visual Studio.

Answer (score 18):

If you're only working on Windows I'd say it boils down to preference.
Otherwise, the clear advantage Qt Creator has over VS is that it's cross platform and moving platforms while keeping your IDE is a clean winner.

If you only work on Windows and have experience working with VS, then you might be more comfortable using something you already know.

Obviously Qt Creator is a lot more Qt-oriented. Every common operation while developing with Qt is bound to be easier in Qt Creator since it's primary goal was to be a tool for developing Qt applications.

Even debugging, which puts VS on top of others, is becoming argumentative when comparing it to Qt Creator, since recently almost every Qt class has a customized debugging representation (read more [here](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2010/04/22/peek-and-poke-vol-3/)).

Answer (score 2):

this is quite an open question, but here's my point of view: with VS you get a true Integrated Development Environment which for me means:

- support a whole lot of languages
- is 'all-in'one', no need switching between programs
- great editor
- very great debugger
- very customizable and extendable, good macro capabilities, good integration with other products, rather mature in comparision with Qt Creator

The only reason I use Qt creator is becasue of the Gui designer actually, pretty much all other tasks can be done by VS.
That doesn't necessarily mean one is better than the other though, I'd just say one is better at performing certan tasks than the other. Use the right tool for each job.

Answer (score 0):

#### **It's a choice based on needs and preferation**

It comes down to:

- What do you want to develop?
- What do you need for that development? (Heavy development or simple projects?)
  Do you need certain libraries? Or a certain debugger?
- What is your preferation of tools by hand? Do you need git support? Is cvs also good enough?
- Do you like the look of the IDE? Because a beautiful IDE usually motivates you while ugly ones distroy this motivation.

With this said: go get yourself an IDE or start making one yourself that fits all your needs.
The latter also means money as you can sell that IDE and you'd probably come with a better one as you fix the common mistakes with other IDEs out of experience.

Answer (score -1):

i believe for C++ apps development QT is best more like dot net of C++ ,  VS is good for dot net c# gui apps development.